# Error 1-661qjd while Installing MATLAB R2013b on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install the **R2013b version on 16.04**. It is successfully installed but i am only stuck in activation.
I get an error: `1-661qjd`. Googling shows that this error has been resolved for 12.10 [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/280000). But Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have any files in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` let alone the file named `70-persistent-net.rules`. So the steps in that post don't work out for me. So can someone please tell how to solve this problem for R2013b on 16.04. It seems since Ubuntu 14.04 or maybe even earlier, the file named 70-persistent-net.rules has been discontinued. However, this issue is [solved](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100235-why-can-t-i-activate-matlab-or-start-the-license-manager-in-a-newer-linux-environment?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) in R2014a and later versions and there is no need for a `eth0` interface to exist. But i only have access to R2013b from college licensed and free.

**PS:**
An answer that does not involve restarting the computer would be great, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if there aren't more correct or logical ways of handling this error code. But issuing the following command from the terminal worked for me:

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 down  && time sudo ip link set eno1 name eth0 && time sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

The crux is to rename the active NIC to `eth0`. The more recent versions of MATLAB take care of this issue internally.